# Consider only Lesser number from db value

Tags: sql

I have a DB table with two columns. one column is id and another one is sequence number. But, I have duplicate ids in id column. Whichever has duplicate ids, the sequence number for that ids will have sequence. Like if i have 1005 3 times, the sequence for this is 0, 1 and 2. Below is the example of my table.

```
ID       Sequence
1001     0
1002     0
1003     1
1004     2
1005     0
1005     1
1005     2
1006     4
1006     5
1007     1
1007     2
```

In my above table, 1005, 1006 and 1007 are repeated and it has different different sequence numbers.

Now, I want to omit duplicate numbers from id and that omitted duplicated id should be with higher sequence number.

So, I want result as below

```
ID       Sequence
1001     0
1002     0
1003     1
1004     2
1005     0
1006     4
1007     1
```

And the total count is 7 rows

Comment: Which DBMS ar you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ID, max(Sequense) as Sequense
from tbl
group by ID
```

Comment: This should be min(), as the expected output for ID 1005 is 0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want more then only those two columns from the table, this is typically solved using a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by t.id order by t.sequence) as rn
  from the_table t
) x
where x.rn = 1;
```